# UPDATE/ALTER SQL Table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I am using Oracle SQL developer and I have my database with two tables

first table ra_stat:

[image]

second table clovek:

[image]

I need to write query, where I set the column "stat_id" with value from the first table ra_stat column "kod"

So result will be

```
Adam | SK | 1
Ferko | SK | 1 
Jozko | CZ | 2
```

Thank you !

Comment: So, have you learned about JOINs yet? If not, time to go and read up on them. If so, have you *tried* to write the query? If so, please add that to your question and explain why/how it's not working.

Comment: Also, we generally prefer sample data as *text* (preferably as a ready made `INSERT` script or similar) over *images*. We can't copy & paste images into our editors and start working with your data. We don't need the typing practice!

Comment: Wait a minute, never store same data twice. Either store those values in ra_stat _or_ in clovek, but not in both tables.

Comment: Do you want to (permanently) update the column stat_id? Or do you just want to get that new value as part of a query result.

Comment: Thank you for downvotes .... -.-" sorry that I am new in SQL ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inner join with a where exists

```
UPDATE clovek SET clovek.stat_id = (
    SELECT ra_stat.kod
    FROM ra_stat 
    WHERE clovek.kod_krajiny  = table2.kod_krajiny )
WHERE  EXISTS (
      SELECT ra_stat.kod
      FROM ra_stat 
      WHERE clovek.kod_krajiny  = table2.kod_krajiny );
```

Answer (score 2):

Straight forward, using a subquery:

```
UPDATE CLOVEK
       SET STAT_ID = (SELECT KOD
                             FROM RA_STAT
                             WHERE RA_STAT.KOD_KRAJINY = CLOVEK.KOD_KRAJINY);
```